# Como relacionar de muchos a muchos en Eloquent (Laravel)

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

Estoy usando MySQL como base de datos y Eloquent como ORM.

He estado creando una página que es de comida o de platos, en la cual ya tengo relacionadas las **comidas** con los **chef** que la preparan, tal que los tengo así:

#### Tabla `foods` (comidas)

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('foods', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title', 50);
        $table->integer('creator_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('image', 300);
        $table->text('description');
        $table->enum('type', ['breakfast', 'lauch', 'dinner', 'snack']);
        $table->enum('status', ['active', 'inactive']);
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('creator_id')->references('id')->on('creators');
    });
}
```

#### Tabla `menus`

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('menus', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->enum('dia_semana', [
            'lunes',
            'martes',
            'miercoles',
            'jueves',
            'viernes',
            'sabado',
            'domingo',
        ]);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Lo que quiero es relacionar esas dos tablas para que quede algo así:
3 `foods` estarían en un `menu`, pero esas 3 comidas que están en ese menú puedes estar en varios menús del día. Ejemplo:

**food1, food2, food3** estarían en el *menu1* que son los *lunes*, 
otro row: **food1, food4, food5** el cual se repite el *food1* serían del *menu2* de los días *martes* y así sucesivamente.

Aún no se me ha ocurrido como hacerlo, así que necesito un poco de ayuda de como podría hacer esa relación en la tabla alterna de muchos a muchos `food_menu`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que realmente necesitas a mi entender es crear un tabla intermedia para poder hacer una relación N a N entre Food y Menú por lo tanto una Comida puede estar en varios Menus y un Menú puede tener muchas comidas

Esto te generaría una row por cada relación pero cumple el funcionamiento que quieres lograr

Esto puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('food_menu', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_food');
        $table->unsignedInteger('id_menu');
        $table->primary(["id_food","id_menu"]);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Luego en tus modelos Food y Menu haces la relacion entre ellos:

```
class Menu extends Model

    public function foods()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Food::class, 'food_menu', 'id_menu', 'id_food')->withTimestamps();
    }

    // todo lo demas
}

class Food extends Model

    public function menus()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Menu::class, 'food_menu', 'id_food', 'id_menu')->withTimestamps();
    }

     // todo lo demas
}
```

Luego por ultimo si quieres obtener todos las comidas que pertenecen a un menu, digamos el de id 10. Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
//foods es el nombre del metodo en el modelo Menu que arma la relacion
$comidas = Menu::find(10)->foods;
```

Espero que pueda servirte de ayuda

Saludos!

Comment: gracias, solo necesitaba una idea, estaba cansado y no se me ocurria nada