# Ayuda con la recogida multiselect Laravel 6

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Trato de programar una selección múltiple donde los datos seleccionados se extraen de una tabla base de datos llamada `Firma` y se guardan en otra tabla llamada `Contratos`, al hacerlo me da el siguiente error.

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '["2","3"]' for column juridico.contratos.firma_id at row 1 (SQL: update contratos set Nom_Entidad = Empresa de Producciones de Aluminio, Metalica y Electrica, No_Contrato = 569874536, Dir_Entidad = Calle 4, Telf_Entidad = 58796523, Importe = 547896, Fecha_Inicial = 2020-04-28, Fecha_Final = 2020-05-01, Suplementos = Test, Tipo_Contrato = servicio, firma_id = ["2","3"], firma_operar_id = 9, contratos.updated_at = 2020-05-18 14:14:46 where id = 3)

**Vista:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="firma_id">Autorizados a firmar Contratos</label>
    <select id="firma_id" class="form-control" name="firma_id[]" multiple>
        @foreach ($firmas->all() as $firmas)
            <option value="{{ $firmas['id'] }}"> {{ $firmas -> nombres }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

**ContratosController.php**

```
public function create()
{
    //
    $firmas = Firmas::all();
    $firmas_operar = Firmas_Operar::all();

    return view('contratos.create', compact('firmas','firmas_operar'));
}

public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        $datosContratos = request()->except(['_token', '_method']);
        Contratos::where('id', '=', $id)->update($datosContratos);

        //$contrato = Contratos::findOrFail($id);
        // return view('contratos.edit', compact('contrato'));

        return redirect('contratos')->with('Mensaje', 'Contrato modificado correctamente');

    }
```

Comment: ya actualice el codigo amigo

Comment: El error dice que estás queriendo insertar ` '["2","3"]'` pero esa columna espera un número entero. ¿Tienes definida la relación entre Firma y Contrato?¿Podrías mostrarla? También explicarnos cómo debería funcionar... Por lo que intentas hacer, "Un Contrato puede tener Muchas Firmas", pero ¿"Una Firma puede tener Muchos Contratos" o "Una Firma pertenece a solo Un Contrato"?

Comment: cuando voy a crear un contrato me da el siguiente error producto de el multiselect : ErrorException
Array to string conversion

Comment: ahi te mostre la relacion entre las tablas un contratos puede tener muchas firmas, y una firma puede tener muchos contratos, el problema es que quiero guardar el nombre de varias firmas en el contrato

Comment: `public function firmas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Firmas');
    }                                                                                                                              public function contratos()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Contratos');
        }   `

Comment: Con ese esquema de BD no podrás, solo te permitirá una firma por contrato. Tendrías que crear una tabla pivot y definir una relación [Muchos-a-Muchos](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). Esta respuesta también te puede ayudar [Como relacionar de muchos a muchos en Eloquent](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/181798/92278)

Comment: o sea tendria que crear un nuevo modelo para crear una tabla nueva?? cambiandole las relaciones a cada tabla de mucho a mucho??

Comment: No, no hace falta otro modelo, sólo crear la tabla pivot y redefinir la relación para que sea 'Muchos a Muchos' en vez de 'Uno a Muchos'.

Comment: muchas gracias.. y disculpa el tiempo robado :)

Comment: es posible hacer un pivote donde por ejemlpo entre 3 tablas.. o sea si puedo apuntar 2 tablas secundarias hacia la principal donde esas 2 tablas tienen las mismas relaciones hacia la principal??