# MultiSelect almacenar datos en BBDD con Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, multiselect

Tengo el siguiente multiselect en mi vista:

```
  <label for="tag_id">{{ __('Seleccionar etiquetas') }}</label> <a href="#addTag" class="text-link link--right-icon float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addTag">{{ __('Crear tag') }} <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <select id="tag_id[]" name="tag_id[]" class="custom-select" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach ($tags as $tag)
        <option value="{{ $tag->id }}">{{ $tag->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
  </select>
```

El tag_id esta en mi tabla de articles, por otra parte existe otra tabla con los nombres de las etiquetas que ya esta relacionada. Muestra todos los tags sin problemas. Necesito almacenar en mi base de datos todos los campos que seleccione en mi multiselect, actualmente solo me almacena uno. En mi controlador tengo el siguiente código:

**Update:**

```
public function update(ArticleRequest $request, $id)
{
    $articles = Article::find($id);
    $articles->update($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('blog')->with('status', __('Your article has been successfully updated.'));
}
```

**Store:**

```
public function store(ArticleRequest $request)
{
    $articles = new Article($request->all());
    $articles->slug = Str::slug($request->title);
    $articles->save();
    return redirect()->route('blog')->with('status', __('Your article has been created correctly.'));
}
```

Completo la información añadiendo la estructura de mis tablas:

**Tags:**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->string('name', 64);
        $table->string('slug', 128)->unique();

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Artículos:**

```
{
    Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('category_id');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('tag_id');
        $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags');

        $table->string('title', 128);
        $table->string('slug', 128)->unique();
        $table->longtext('description');
        $table->mediumtext('abstract');
        $table->string('meta_description', 128);
        $table->enum('mark', ['on', 'off'])->default('off');
        $table->string('image');

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

En mis modelos de artículos y tags tengo lo siguiente:

**Tags Model**

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    /**
    * Protect variables articles public.
    */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug'];
    /**
    * We define the relationships between tables.
    */
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article');
    }
}
```

**Artículos Model**

```
class Article extends Model
{
    /**
    * Protect variables articles public.
    */
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'user_id', 'slug', 'description', 'abstract', 'tag_id', 'meta_description', 'category_id', 'mark', 'image'];
    /**
    * We define the relationships between tables.
    */
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }

    public function tag()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Tag');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Que es tu "tabla de post"?¿Y qué significa " existe otra tabla con los nombres de las etiquetas que ya esta relacionada"? Ten en cuenta que no sabemos nada de tu proyecto. Tampoco sabemos que hay en el request, y solo muestras que haces `->update($request->all());`.

Comment: De hecho necesitamos saber en que parte del codigo es que tienes el problema, ¿Como lo quieres hacer? y ¿Que haz hecho? de forma mas detallada, por que a como lo comentas se me ocurre que lo hagas con un `::whereIn()`

Comment: Perdonar, edito mi pregunta añadiendo la estructura de mi base de datos, tanto la tabla tags y la tabla articles, que son las implicadas. Perdón, mi tabla post no existe, le llamo articles.

Comment: Por la estructura de la tabla `articulos` solo podrás relacionar un tag a cada artículo. Creo que lo que tendrías que hacer ahí es una relación muchos a muchos. O polimórfica, si quieres relacionar las etiquetas tambien a otras entidades además de a los artículos

Comment: ¿Me podrías ayudar? ¿Debería hacer una tabla intermedia? no soy experto en esto. Actualizo el mi pregunta añadiendo lo que tengo en la parte de mi modelo.

Comment: Tendrías que crear una tabla intermedia y definir una relación [Muchos-a-Muchos](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many). Esta [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/181780/como-relacionar-de-muchos-a-muchos-en-eloquent-laravel/181798#181798) también te puede ayudar Como relacionar de muchos a muchos en Eloquent, solo reemplaza los nombres.